# What sectarian doctrines of sects that deny Indra is Brahman would be violated by scriptural statements that say Indra is Brahman?

Tags: brahman, indra, sects

(from quora)

> He has the power to resurrect the mortals and grant others immortality

Anusure Mallikarjun

My answer is based on vedas which says lord Indra is the name of supreme Brahman or supreme reality -:

> Indra is called as the Lord of the Universe, the all pervader and the Supreme Lord in many Vedic verses. Here are some examples from RigVeda:

> रूपं-रूपं परतिरूपो बभूव तदस्य रूपं परतिचक्षणाय |
> इन्द्रो मायाभिः पुरुरूप ईयते युक्ता हयस्य हरयःशता दश || (RigVeda 6.47.18)

> In every figure he hath been the mode: this is his only form for us to look on. Indra assumes many form by his Maya, for his Bay Steeds are yoked, ten times a hundred.

> यो विश्वस्य जगतः पराणतस पतिर्यो बरह्मणे परथमो गा अविन्दत |
> इन्द्रो यो दस्यून्रधरानवातिरन म... || (RigVeda 1.101.5)

> He who is Lord of all the world that moves and breathes, who for the Brahman first before all found the Cows; Indra who cast the Dasyus down beneath his feet,—him girt by Maruts we invoke to be our Friend.

At HSE too, we have

[Which Vedic verses describe Indra as Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman)

To non-sectarian Hindus, there is no need to "re-interpret" these direct statements.  Most deities have done questionable things and incidents like Ahalya (many consider it an interpolation) need not take away from Indra's supremacy.

Are there sectarian reasons behind belittling Indra as a mere post?

EDIT: this question is not asking for pros and cons of saying "Indra is Brahman".

It is asking **which sects** would find their foundational doctrines questioned **if** Indra is Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that Indra is only censured in the sectarian smritis, is wrong. Indra is censured as early as the Rig Veda Brahmanas:

Aitareya Brahmana of the Rig Veda:
[image]

Translation:

> “He has dishonored Vishvarup, son of Tvastar. He has slain Vritra. He
> has handed over the Yatis to the Salavrkeyas. He has slain the
> Arurmaghas. He has struck Brhaspati. Indra is deprived of Soma
> Drinking".

The gods exclude Indra "paryavRnjan".

Indra was praised as a great deity before his sins (during the composition of the Rig Samhit). But after these sins, and after his embarrassment in the Govardhana Hill incident, he is no longer revered as a great deity.

Therefore, Indra is not Brahman since he has committed sins, as proven by the Vedas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136395/discussion-on-answer-by-ikshvaku-what-sectarian-doctrines-of-sects-that-deny-ind).