# How does Veda Vyasa reconcile the praise of Indra as Brahman with this citation from Aitareya Brahmana?

Tags: mahabharata, brahman, indra, aitareya-brahmana

[Who was the earliest Vedic scholar to claim that only Indra and no other Deva is Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36907/who-was-the-earliest-vedic-scholar-to-claim-that-only-indra-and-no-other-deva-is)

In answer to the above question, Mahabharata is cited:

> BhagavAn veda vyAsa considers Indra as the supreme brahman in the Mahabharata. Below is a prayer to Indra by Kadru -

> Adi parva 21 (Mahabharata BORI edition)

But in the answer to this question:

[What sectarian doctrines of sects that deny Indra is Brahman would be violated by scriptural statements that say Indra is Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51518/what-sectarian-doctrines-of-sects-that-deny-indra-is-brahman-would-be-violated-b)

A citation from Aitareya Brahmana is made

> “He has dishonored Vishvarup, son of Tvastar. He has slain Vritra. He has handed over the Yatis to the Salavrkeyas. He has slain the Arurmaghas. He has struck Brhaspati. Indra is deprived of Soma Drinking".

Veda Vyasa had to have known about this - so how does he or any other commentator justify his praise of Indra in the Mshabharata?